# Changing File Structure View

Tags: windows-7

My USB's File Structure View has for some reason now changed so that while it shows the files in "Detail" view (where it shows Name, File Size, ect) it will now show the files grouped as their file extensions (as in "Folder" has all the folder in it, ect) and this has also turned off some of the columns such as "File Size"

How do i restore/change this back?

Im running Windows 7 home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open Windows Explorer
- Right-click on the USB drive, and select `Properties`
- Click `Customize`, and select `General Items` in the "Optimize this folder for:" drop-down.

[image]

- Then in the View menu, change the Group option to `(None)`

[image]

Comment: Haha! Being a bit new to 7, i forgot about the hiding of that menu, as that was the first thing i was looking for to fix this. Thanks, worked fine, USB now looks as it did before